# Same date different long time

Tags: java, date

i've a object Date as for example this date "Fri Aug 01 00:00:00 CDT 2014" that through this validation:

```
Date fechaInicio = filtros.containsKey("dateFechaInicio") ? Fecha.getMinDate(Fecha.getFecha(filtros.get("dateFechaInicio").toString())) : Fecha.getMinDate(null);
```

Where map filtros contains the key "dateFechaFinal" it will to method Fecha.getMaxDate(Date date) that does

```
    public static Date getMinDate(Date fecha) {
    Calendar fechaMin = Calendar.getInstance();
    fechaMin.setTime(fecha != null ? fecha : new Date());
    fechaMin.set(fechaMin.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                fechaMin.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                fecha != null ? fechaMin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) : fechaMin.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                                fechaMin.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                                fechaMin.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE),
                                fechaMin.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
    return fechaMin.getTime();
}
```

And return a new Date, if this method receives a date return this Long time 1406869200806 , but if receives a date equal to null the method takes the first day from month for example  "Fri Aug 01 00:00:00 CDT 2014" but now return this Long time 1406869200000..

"filtros obtained a String that method getFecha() convert to new Date"

Why happen it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're only setting values down to the second, so the *millisecond* part is left at whatever it was from `new Date()`. Your description isn't entirely clear, but I suspect you just want:

```
fechaMin.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Alternatively, use a better API, such as [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) or the `java.time` API in Java 8.

Comment: is just that i needed. working fine , thanks so much and apologize my description and my english i know it's very bad. rewards (: